# don't know why the site is pushing to right on mobile

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

we are working on a site and it's behaving very strange on mobile. When it's loaded first time on mobile (we're using chrome's mobile emulator), it loads fine and responsive, but as soon as we scroll, it just pushed to right, sometime it don't and mostly it does, we've tried everything but couldn't find what the issue is. We are stuck. Can anyone of you please take a look and tell us where the problem is. Here is the site,

Note: Site is only causing problem on mobile not on desktop

http://bari-ladat.meuhedet.co.il/

Comment: From playing around on the website it looks like the website isn't adjusting when changing resolutions so going from desktop -> mobile means half the content is dynamically changing.

Comment: go to mobile mode, refresh the page, page loads fine but as soon as u scroll, it move to right, sometimes it don't happen

Comment: Looks like `direction` is causing the problem. Try to change your direction only in `.pushmenu-wrapper`.

Comment: this website is in Hebrew and it's RTL, if i put direction: ltr; it solves the problem but all the text becomes LTR too which is not good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `style.css:1728` adjust your `.footer_black` to `direction: ltr;` and in `style.css:1683` change your `.kred-dt img` to `left: 0;`. That solves it for me, although I can't read Hebrew so double check if it affects the text in any way, if so simply change the text's `direction` (in a span for instance) to `rtl`.

Comment: it solved my problem @Will. Really helpful. Thank you